# How did War Emergency Power work?

Tags: engine, wwii

Someone can explain how WEP (War Emergency Power) worked on the planes of the Second World War? And if it was really effective during a combat?

Comment: is it related to [water injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_injection_(engine)#Use_in_aircraft)?

Comment: @ManuH Not directly.  Water injection was sometimes used to reduce detonation at very high manifold pressures, but War Emergency Power could be used without it -- water injection was commonly used for Takeoff Power to avoid the stress on the engine that War Emergency Power produced.

Answer (score 15):

Generally, [War Emergency Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_emergency_power) was a power setting that was available, but exceeded the engine's long term running condition rating.  It was usually specified in manifold pressure, and primarily applied to supercharged or turbocharged engines (which was most of the high performance piston engines by the end of the War).

The way it works was much like how it works in modern jets (where it often specifies afterburner operation): There was a stop on the throttle and a warning mark on the manifold pressure gauge that warned the pilot not to exceed those settings, as well as a specification in the manual for the longest permitted time in War Emergency Power setting.  To engage this setting, the pilot either had to manipulate the throttle lever in an unusual direction (pull up, push sideways) or break an actual wire with a push strong enough not to be done by accident, in order to bypass the stop.  In aircraft where it was used, the wire served to notify ground crews that WEP had been used.

Once engaged, War Emergency Power would give anything from 10% to 20% more total horsepower (in most cases, though the last version of the P-51 got roundly 60% increase), and a significantly increased rate of engine parts wear and risk of failure (blown gaskets, thrown connecting rods, even holed pistons from detonation if the fuel wasn't quite up to spec).  This doesn't seem like much, but 20% additional power would amount to 10 knots or more of additional level flight airspeed, or several hundred feet per minute of increase in climb rate -- it could make all the difference in air combat, when fighters of one force were often quite closely matched to those of the other in terms of performance.

Comment: In other words, it was just like "push to pass" is in modern auto racing. That gives you an increase in turbo boost or battery power so you can make a pass on the car in front of you (or defend against the car behind), but it causes additional engine wear or uses battery power that takes time to regenerate. It's a short-term boost that can come at a long-term cost.

Comment: @FreeMan Pretty much.  The manufacturer would rate the engine for so many minutes in War Emergency Power and require a detail inspection afterward -- minimum of an oil change (for inline engines that didn't run total-loss oiling), stick a borescope in every spark plug hole to check condition of pistons, etc.  Much of this didn't get done at a front line base, of course, but there was a lot of "built way better than claimed" in those days, at least in US aircraft.

Comment: The limit was normally set by copper witness wire across the throttle slot which set the normal wide open throttle position, called the "gate".  Copper wire was used to provide a clear indication to maintenance that WEP was selected in the event that the pilot neglected to bring it up. Copper witness wire provided a usable mechanical stop for setting the normal forward limit of throttle travel, but could be broken by a sufficiently strong push. Going to WEP was "breaking the gates" or "busting the gates" or "through the gates".  My father flew C-47s in WW2 and used WEP once to clear terrain.